# Olá pessoal, estou começando um curso de vuejs, quando rodo os comandos npm install -g @vue/cli e vue serve, acontecem alguns erros

Tags: vue.js, ubuntu, npm

[inserir a descrição da imagem aqui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a51P5.png)

[inserir a descrição da imagem aqui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b2oyk.png)

Possuo um arquivo nessa pasta chamado App.vue com o seguinte conteúdo:
<template:

## Hello World

Answer (score -3):

Pelo que notei nas imagens você executou o comando vue serve logo após rodar o `npm install`.

O `@vue/cli` é um pacote urilizado para facilitar o fluxo de desenvolvimento com o Vue, e uma das suas funcionalidades é justamente a criação de projetos. Então, após instala-lo é preciso executar o comando `vue create` para gerar um novo projeto. Ex:

```
vue create my-awesome-project
```

Com isto será gerado um projeto chamado my-awesome-project, no seu terminal navegue até esta pasta, e apenas em seguida execute o projeto:

```
 cd my-awesome-project
 npm run serve
```

### Atualizações do Vue

Importante notar que o Vue recebeu algumas atualizações e inclusive alterou a forma "padrão" para se criar novos projetos, inclusive adicionaram este pacote @vue/cli em modo de manutenção, dê uma olhada na documentação [aqui](https://vuejs.org/guide/quick-start.html) para aprender mais sobre como criar projetos com o Vue.

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).